# Generate random numbers for groups R

Tags: r, random, group-by, numbers

I want to generate the same random number for groups. Unfortunately, my following code generates random number for each row.

```
randomised <- data %>%
  group_by(`ID`)%>%
  mutate(random = sample(1:100,n(), replace = TRUE))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just select 1 value from `sample` which will be recycled for all the values in the group.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(ID)%>% mutate(random = sample(100,1))
```

Or in base R :

```
data$random <- with(data, ave(seq_along(ID), ID,FUN = function(x) sample(100, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option in `data.table`:

```
setDT(data)[, random := sample(100, 1), ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why we need this,  if we are trying to anonymise the IDs (*cyl* column in *mtcars* example data), then this is pretty random to me:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(random = as.integer(as.factor(cyl)))
```